# Sometimes wrapping is not working as expected

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking, paragraphs, wrap

I am using TeXworks and the documentclass article but sometimes the word wrapping is not as expected.
How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Zahlenkonvertierung}
\subsection{Lösungsidee}
\subsubsection{Dec2Dual}
Um eine positive, ganze Zahl vom Dezimalsystem in das Dualsystem zu konvertieren, kann wie folgt vorgegangen werden: Man führe solange eine ganzzahlige Division der Dezimalzahl durch die Basis 2 des Dualsystems durch, bis das Ergebnis 0 ergibt. Dabei ist der Restwert jeder Teildivision eine Stelle der Dualzahl, beginnend beim \glqq Least Signifcant Bit\grqq{} und endend beim \glqq Most Significant Bit\grqq{}.\\\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you not liking all five of those lines, or just the first one?  Could you create a MWE with this paragraph and the minimal preamble?  Are you using babel or polyglossia?

Comment: texworks isn't involved here that's just the editor that you used to write the file. Please always show the example as text as a complete small document that shows the problem. Assuming that you have specified the correct language for hyphenation, you can check which `\showhyphens{konvertieren}` where that word will break and can add more hypenation points if needed, or try `\sloppy`  or re-word the paragraph or...

Comment: i do not like the line-break of the first line. it should be like all the other lines.
here is a MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/read/sfstcrqnstkh
i am fairly new to latex. i did not specify any hyphenation. i will look into it. thanks

Comment: It is preferable to post your code here, so I've taken the liberty of doing that.  I see that you've loaded babel, but you've not done anything to tell TeX what language you're using.  This means that TeX is using the english hyphenation rules, which doesn't turn out well for other languages.

Comment: You are not selecting a language for babel.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `babel`, but you didn't tell TeX which language you were using, so it assumed you were typing in english.  If you change your package to `\usepackage[german]{babel}`, then you get

[image: code output]

You should also delete the `\\\\` from the end of your text.  It's causing an underfull hbox warning.  If you need some extra vertical space, then you can begin the next paragraph with `\bigskip`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me out!